# Problems with SED in Ansible playbook

Tags: sed, ansible

I'm installing Docker on some hosts and using Ansible playbook to do this.  However, we have a startup script for Consul that breaks when docker is installed, as Docker adds a virtual NIC and adds an extra value to the variable.

Original Variables

```
NODEIP=`hostname -I`
NODE=`hostname -I |sed  's/[.]/-/g'`
```

I can manually change them to the following and this works.

```
NODEIP=$(hostname -I | grep -o "[^ ]\\+" | awk /^10\./"{print $1}")
NODE=$(hostname -I | grep -o "[^ ]\+" | awk /^10\./"{print $1}" |sed  "s/[.]/-/g")
```

However, I need to add these to an Ansible playbook.  I've modified the variable for NODE and it gets updated in the script, but NODEIP does not.  See sample playbook code below.

```
name: Fix consul startup script for Docker virtual network interface
      shell: sed -i 's/NODEIP=`hostname -I`/s_.*_NODEIP=$(hostname -I | grep -o \"[^ ]\\+\" | awk /^10\./\"{print \$1}\")' filename
      shell: sed -i '/NODE=`hostname -I |sed/s_.*_NODE=$(echo $NODEIP|sed  's/[.]/-/g')_' filename
```

I'm going insane trying to get this to work properly.  Can anyone help?

Comment: See if you can get the required information from Ansible [facts and magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html) instead.

Comment: `Fix consul startup script for Docker virtual network interface` Consider using ansible templates to generate consul configuration, instead of using shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for the input.  Here's what I ended up coming up with (had to escape some characters with backslashes).  Delighted it works

```
- name: replace NODEIP variable in consul startup script
  lineinfile:
   path: filename
   regexp: '^NODEIP='
   line: "NODEIP=$(hostname -I | grep -o \"[^ ]\\+\" | awk /^10\\./\"{print $1}\")"
   backrefs: yes

- name: replace NODE variable in consul startup script
  lineinfile:
   path: filename
   regexp: '^NODE='
   line: "NODE=$(hostname -I | grep -o \"[^ ]\\+\" | awk /^10\\./\"{print $1}\" |sed  \"s/[.]/-/g\")"
   backrefs: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you run an ansible-playbook, it will [gather_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/gather_facts_module.html) by default. This task will populate your ansible-playbook execution with the variables listed here: [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts)

In your case, you are looking for:

```
NODEIP={{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
NODE={{ ansible_hostname }}
```

Comment: Thank you - is there a way to update an existing script on the host using this.  I need to find and replace the existing lines in the script - hence why I was using "sed"

Comment: Ansible has the following module for that: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html

Answer (score 0):

Below code should solve your requirement

```
- name: Command for NodeIP
  shell: hostname -I | grep -o "[^ ]\\+" | awk /^10\./"{print $1}"
  register: NODEIP

- name: Command for NodeName
  shell: hostname -I | grep -o "[^ ]\+" | awk /^10\./"{print $1}" |sed  "s/[.]/-/g"
  register: NODE
```

Above code will store command output to NODEIP and NODE variables respectively.

To learn more about usage of ansible return values, refer https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html

Comment: Thank you - I'm actually trying to edit an existing script on the fly as part of the playbook running.  This is why I'm trying to use "sed"

Is there a better way to do this with Ansible?  If you look at my ansible shell commands you see I put "filename" at the end, which is the file I'm trying to update.

Comment: Yes, As per the code snippet shared by you, I assume you are attempting to search and replace the occurrences with NODEIP and NODE in file called 'filename.'

You can try using replace module of ansible https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html

this will work as good as sed and you just need to specify file path, regex and string to replace.